# Snake game in python Turtle.update() causes problems

Tags: python, turtle-graphics

So I was trying to create a game of snake using python but I seem to get this error message

```
Traceback (most recent call last):   
File "C:\Users\user\source\repos\PythonApplication1\PythonApplication1\PythonApplication1.py", line 85, in <module>
    wn.update()   
File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Python39_64\lib\turtle.py", line 1304, in update
    t._update_data()   
File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Python39_64\lib\turtle.py", line 2647, in _update_data
    self.screen._incrementudc()   
File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Python39_64\lib\turtle.py", line 1293, in _incrementudc
    raise Terminator turtle.Terminator
```

I have tried some solutions I saw online but none of them worked

```
import turtle
import time
import random

delay = 0.1
score = 0

wn = turtle.Screen()
wn.title("Snake Game")
wn.bgcolor("blue")

wn.setup(width=600 ,height=600)
wn.tracer(0)

#HEAD
head = turtle.Turtle()
head.shape("square")
head.color("white")
head.penup()
head.goto(0,0)
head.direction = "stop"
#FOOD
food = turtle.Turtle()
colors = random.choice(['red','green','black'])
shapes = random.choice(['square','triangle','circle'])
food.speed(0)
food.shape(shapes)
food.color(colors)
food.penup()
food.goto(0,100)



pen = turtle.Turtle()
pen.speed(0)
pen.shape("square")
pen.color("white")
pen.penup()
pen.hideturtle()
pen.goto(0,250)
pen.write("Score : 0 High Score : 0",align="center",font=("candara",24,"bold"))


def goup():
    if head.direction !="down":
        head.direction = "up"

def godown():
    if head.direction !="up":
        head.direction ="down"

def goleft():
    if head.direction !="right":
        head.direction ="left"

def goright():
    if head.direction !="left":
        head.direction ="right"

def move():
    if head.direction == "up":
        y=head.ycor()
        head.sety(y+20)
    if head.direction == "down":
        y = head.ycor()
        head.sety(y-20)
    if head.direction == "left":
        x = head.xcor()
        head.setx(x-20)
    if head.direction == "right":
        x = head.xcor()
        head.setx(x+20)


wn.listen()
wn.onkeypress(goup,"w")
wn.onkeypress(godown,"s")
wn.onkeypress(goleft,"a")
wn.onkeypress(goright,"d")

segments = []

#Main Gameplay
while True:
    wn.update()
    if head.xcor()>290 or head.xcor()<-290 or head.ycor()>290 or head.ycor()<-290:
        time.sleep(1)
        head.goto(0,0)
        head.direction = "Stop"
        colors = random.choice(['red','blue','green'])
        shapes = random.choice(['square','circle'])
        for segment in segments:
            segments.goto(1000,1000)
        segments.clear()
        score = 0
        delay = 0.1
        pen.clear()
        pen.write("Score : 0 High Score : 0",align="center",font=("candara",24,"bold"))
    if head.distance(food)<20:
        x = random.randint(-270,270)
        y = random.randint(-270,270)

        #Adding segments
        new_segment = turtle.Turtle()
        new_segment.speed(0)
        new_segment.shape("square")
        new_segment.color("orange")
        new_segment.penup()
        segments.append(new_segment)
        delay -= 0.001
        score += 10
        if score > high_score:
            high_score = score
        pen.clear()
        pen.write("Score : {} High Score : {} ".format(score,high_score),align="center", font=("candara",24,"bold"))

        for index in range(len(segments)-1,0,-1):
            x = segments[index-1].xcor()
            y = segments[index-1].ycor()
            segments[index].goto(x,y)
        if len(segments) > 0:
            x = head.xcor()
            y = head.ycor()
            segments[0].goto(x,y)
        move()
        for segment in segments:
            if segment.distance(head) < 20:
                time.sleep(1)
                head.goto(0,0)
                head.direction = "Stop"
                colors = random.choice(['red','blue','green'])
                shapes = random.choice(['square','circle'])
                for segment in segments:
                    segment.goto(1000,1000)
                segment.clear()

                score = 0 
                delay = 0.1
                pen.clear()
                pen.write("Score : {} High Score : {} ".format(score,high_score),align="center", font=("candara",24,"bold"))
        time.sleep(delay)

wn.mainloop()
```

Comment: provide a [mre]

Comment: I get this problem only when I close window with Turtle. And this is normal because  when I close window then it still runs `while`-loop and `update()` tries to access window which is already closed. You would have to add listener which check if window is closed and stop `while` loop. OR you should use [ontimer](https://docs.python.org/3/library/turtle.html#turtle.ontimer) instead of `while True` and `delay` - and maybe it will stop function when you close window.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**EDIT:**

Original code has wrong indentations and some elements doesn't work.

---

I get this problem only when I close window with Turtle. And this is normal behaviour because when I close window then it still runs `while`-loop and `wm.update()` tries to access window which is already closed.

It would need to assign function which will be executed when window is closed and this function should stop `while` loop. But this need to use `while running:` with `running = True` and access `root` window created by `tkinter` and assign function (which will set `running = False`) to even `"WM_DELETE_WINDOW"`

```
# ... code ...

running = True

def on_closing():
    global running
    
    running = False
    #root.destroy()
    
canvas = turtle.getcanvas()
root = canvas.winfo_toplevel()
root.protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW", on_closing)

while running:
   # ...code...
```

---

Full working code.

BTW: it doesn't need `mainloop` if you runs own loop with `update()`

```
import turtle
import time
import random

delay = 0.1
score = 0

wn = turtle.Screen()
wn.title("Snake Game")
wn.bgcolor("blue")

wn.setup(width=600 ,height=600)
wn.tracer(0)

#HEAD
head = turtle.Turtle()
head.shape("square")
head.color("white")
head.penup()
head.goto(0,0)
head.direction = "stop"
#FOOD
food = turtle.Turtle()
colors = random.choice(['red','green','black'])
shapes = random.choice(['square','triangle','circle'])
food.speed(0)
food.shape(shapes)
food.color(colors)
food.penup()
food.goto(0,100)



pen = turtle.Turtle()
pen.speed(0)
pen.shape("square")
pen.color("white")
pen.penup()
pen.hideturtle()
pen.goto(0,250)
pen.write("Score : 0 High Score : 0",align="center",font=("candara",24,"bold"))


def goup():
    if head.direction !="down":
        head.direction = "up"

def godown():
    if head.direction !="up":
        head.direction ="down"

def goleft():
    if head.direction !="right":
        head.direction ="left"

def goright():
    if head.direction !="left":
        head.direction ="right"

def move():
    if head.direction == "up":
        y=head.ycor()
        head.sety(y+20)
    if head.direction == "down":
        y = head.ycor()
        head.sety(y-20)
    if head.direction == "left":
        x = head.xcor()
        head.setx(x-20)
    if head.direction == "right":
        x = head.xcor()
        head.setx(x+20)


wn.listen()
wn.onkeypress(goup,"w")
wn.onkeypress(godown,"s")
wn.onkeypress(goleft,"a")
wn.onkeypress(goright,"d")

segments = []

running = True

def on_closing():
    global running
    
    running = False
    root.destroy()
    
canvas = turtle.getcanvas()
root = canvas.winfo_toplevel()
root.protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW", on_closing)

#Main Gameplay
while running:
    wn.update()
    if head.xcor()>290 or head.xcor()<-290 or head.ycor()>290 or head.ycor()<-290:
        time.sleep(1)
        head.goto(0,0)
        head.direction = "Stop"
        colors = random.choice(['red','blue','green'])
        shapes = random.choice(['square','circle'])
        for segment in segments:
            segments.goto(1000,1000)
        segments.clear()
        score = 0
        delay = 0.1
        pen.clear()
        pen.write("Score : 0 High Score : 0",align="center",font=("candara",24,"bold"))
    if head.distance(food)<20:
        x = random.randint(-270,270)
        y = random.randint(-270,270)

        #Adding segments
        new_segment = turtle.Turtle()
        new_segment.speed(0)
        new_segment.shape("square")
        new_segment.color("orange")
        new_segment.penup()
        segments.append(new_segment)
        delay -= 0.001
        score += 10
        if score > high_score:
            high_score = score
        pen.clear()
        pen.write("Score : {} High Score : {} ".format(score,high_score),align="center", font=("candara",24,"bold"))

    # --- after `if` ---

    for index in range(len(segments)-1,0,-1):
        x = segments[index-1].xcor()
        y = segments[index-1].ycor()
        segments[index].goto(x,y)
    if len(segments) > 0:
        x = head.xcor()
        y = head.ycor()
        segments[0].goto(x,y)
    move()
    for segment in segments:
        if segment.distance(head) < 20:
            time.sleep(1)
            head.goto(0,0)
            head.direction = "Stop"
            colors = random.choice(['red','blue','green'])
            shapes = random.choice(['square','circle'])
            for segment in segments:
                segment.goto(1000,1000)
            segment.clear()

            score = 0 
            delay = 0.1
            pen.clear()
            pen.write("Score : {} High Score : {} ".format(score,high_score),align="center", font=("candara",24,"bold"))
    time.sleep(delay)

#wn.mainloop()
```

---

OR you should use [ontimer(func, time)](https://docs.python.org/3/library/turtle.html#turtle.ontimer) instead of `while`-loop and `time.sleep()` - and then it should stop it when you close window

```
def gameloop():
    wn.update()
    # ... code without `while` and without `sleep`

    # run again 
    wn.ontimer(gameloop, 1000) # time in millisecons

# --- 

# run first time
wn.ontimer(gameloop, 1000) # time in millisecons

wn.mainloop()
```

**BTW:** but it needs to use `global` inside `gameloop` to assign values to global variables instead of local variables.

---

Full code

It needs `mainloop()` which will run `gameloop()` ever 1000 milliseconds.

```
import turtle
import time
import random

delay = 0.1
score = 0

wn = turtle.Screen()
wn.title("Snake Game")
wn.bgcolor("blue")

wn.setup(width=600 ,height=600)
wn.tracer(0)

#HEAD
head = turtle.Turtle()
head.shape("square")
head.color("white")
head.penup()
head.goto(0,0)
head.direction = "stop"
#FOOD
food = turtle.Turtle()
colors = random.choice(['red','green','black'])
shapes = random.choice(['square','triangle','circle'])
food.speed(0)
food.shape(shapes)
food.color(colors)
food.penup()
food.goto(0,100)



pen = turtle.Turtle()
pen.speed(0)
pen.shape("square")
pen.color("white")
pen.penup()
pen.hideturtle()
pen.goto(0,250)
pen.write("Score : 0 High Score : 0",align="center",font=("candara",24,"bold"))


def goup():
    if head.direction !="down":
        head.direction = "up"

def godown():
    if head.direction !="up":
        head.direction ="down"

def goleft():
    if head.direction !="right":
        head.direction ="left"

def goright():
    if head.direction !="left":
        head.direction ="right"

def move():
    if head.direction == "up":
        y=head.ycor()
        head.sety(y+20)
    if head.direction == "down":
        y = head.ycor()
        head.sety(y-20)
    if head.direction == "left":
        x = head.xcor()
        head.setx(x-20)
    if head.direction == "right":
        x = head.xcor()
        head.setx(x+20)


wn.listen()
wn.onkeypress(goup,"w")
wn.onkeypress(godown,"s")
wn.onkeypress(goleft,"a")
wn.onkeypress(goright,"d")

segments = []

high_score = 0

def gameloop():
    global score
    global delay
    global high_score
    # ... etc. ...

    wn.update()

    if head.xcor()>290 or head.xcor()<-290 or head.ycor()>290 or head.ycor()<-290:
        head.goto(0,0)
        head.direction = "Stop"
        colors = random.choice(['red','blue','green'])
        shapes = random.choice(['square','circle'])
        for segment in segments:
            segments.goto(1000,1000)
        segments.clear()
        score = 0
        delay = 0.1
        pen.clear()
        pen.write("Score : 0 High Score : 0",align="center",font=("candara",24,"bold"))
    if head.distance(food)<20:
        x = random.randint(-270,270)
        y = random.randint(-270,270)

        #Adding segments
        new_segment = turtle.Turtle()
        new_segment.speed(0)
        new_segment.shape("square")
        new_segment.color("orange")
        new_segment.penup()
        segments.append(new_segment)
        delay -= 0.001
        score += 10
        if score > high_score:
            high_score = score
        pen.clear()
        pen.write("Score : {} High Score : {} ".format(score,high_score),align="center", font=("candara",24,"bold"))

    # --- after `if` ---

    for index in range(len(segments)-1,0,-1):
        x = segments[index-1].xcor()
        y = segments[index-1].ycor()
        segments[index].goto(x,y)
    if len(segments) > 0:
        x = head.xcor()
        y = head.ycor()
        segments[0].goto(x,y)
    move()
    for segment in segments:
        if segment.distance(head) < 20:
            time.sleep(1)
            head.goto(0,0)
            head.direction = "Stop"
            colors = random.choice(['red','blue','green'])
            shapes = random.choice(['square','circle'])
            for segment in segments:
                segment.goto(1000,1000)
            segment.clear()

            score = 0 
            delay = 0.1
            pen.clear()
            pen.write("Score : {} High Score : {} ".format(score,high_score),align="center", font=("candara",24,"bold"))

    # run again 
    wn.ontimer(gameloop, 1000) # time in millisecons

# --- 

# run first time
wn.ontimer(gameloop, 1000) # time in millisecons

wn.mainloop()  # it needs `mainloop`
```

Comment: it did fix the issue I had but now the game still doesn't work for me at least, i try to press buttons and it doesn't work am I doing something wrong? i'm feeling so dumb xd

Comment: your code didn't work for me even with your original code - maybe first you shouyd use `print()` to see what you have in variables and which part of code is executed. It is called `"print debuging"`

Comment: in version with `ontimer` I forgot second `ontimer` inside `gameloop`.

Comment: after checking code I see you have wrong indentations inside loop - you have `for`-loop and `move()` inside `if` - so it it execured only in some situations - but it should be outside `if` to run it in every loop.